# Uso de base de dados Firebird de um PC para outro

Tags: mysql, firebird

Fiz o backup de uma base de dados Firebird de um PC e o que acontece é que eu coloquei essa base de dados noutro PC mas aí a aplicação diz que a base de dados é exclusiva de outro utilizador ou seja o programa deve fazer alguma verificação de pastas ou nome de utilizador que está na base de dados e o nome do user do PC onde coloquei o backup.

Se criar uma base de dados a partir desse PC aí já não dá erro, pois a BD foi criada nesse PC, já restaurar um backup de outro PC para um PC novo dá erro, alguém me pode ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Qual o usuário do Firebird que você estava utilizando no servidor antigo? Ele está criado no servidor novo?

Verifique através do **[gsec.exe](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/pt_br/fbutils-gsec-interactive-pt_br.html)** no servidor antigo os usuários que existem e crie os usuários no servidor novo.

```dos
gsec -user sysdba -password masterkey
GSEC> display
GSEC> add newuser -pw newuser -fname New -lname User
```